# OAuth2 Bundle Symfony -> Attempted to load class "AbstractGuardAuthenticator" from namespace

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0

I just started using the knpuniversity bundle to authenticate my Discord users under Symfony 7, and I have this error, apparently it comes from here :

Security\Authenticator\SocialAuthenticator.php

when calling AbstractGuardAuthenticator, is the bundle out of date or did I make a mistake when i call SocialAuthenticator ?

class DiscordAuthenticator extends SocialAuthenticator

This is my actual code :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\SocialAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class DiscordAuthenticator extends SocialAuthenticator {

    private RouterInterface $router;
    private ClientRegistry $clientRegistry;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_login'));
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'oauth_check' === $request->attributes->get('_route') && $request->get('service') === 'discord';
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->fetchAccessToken($this->clientRegistry->getClient('discord'));
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        dd($credentials);
    }
}
```

I looked for the error and apparently AbstractGuardAuthenticator no longer exists, but how can I replace it?

Comment: What is "this error"? Please share the full and exact error message

Comment: Have a look to : https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle?tab=readme-ov-file#authenticating-with-the-new-symfony-authenticator

Comment: Please share your full code or try with https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle?tab=readme-ov-file#authenticating-with-the-new-symfony-authenticator